# How do I match products id from api using router dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router, react-router-dom

I wanna display certain product when it's clicked on based on their id from django rest framework api.. I was doing that using match from the react-router-dom v5, but I don't know how to accomplish the same thing with match not existing in v6. I looked at the react-router-dom v6 documentation for a clue and i couldn't find a solution..

ProductScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
//import products from "../../products";
import Rating from "../Rating";
import axios from "axios";

function ProductScreen({ match }) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProduct() {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`);
      setProduct(data);
    }
    fetchProduct();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-dark my-3">
        Go Back
      </Link>

      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Image
            className="imgCustom"
            src={product.image}
            alt={product.name}
          ></Image>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Rating
                value={product.rating}
                text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                color={"f8e825"}
              />
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>Price : ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>Description: ${product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>

        <Col md={3}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Price : </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>$ {product.price}</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Status : </Col>
                  <Col>
                    {product.coutInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button
                  className="btn-block"
                  disabled={product.coutInStock === 0}
                  type="button"
                >
                  Add to Cart
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      {product.name}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useParmas` for this:

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ProductScreen() {
   const { id } = useParams();
   useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchProduct() {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
        setProduct(data);
      }
     fetchProduct();
   }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can use the `useParams` to get the id

```
function ProductScreen({ match }) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProduct() {
      if(id){
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
        setProduct(data);
      }
    }
    fetchProduct();
  }, [id]);
```